# Laravel endpoint fail when is called from NextJs Server Side

Tags: laravel, next.js, cookies

I'm using laravel as API and NextJs, when I called protected endpoints from the client side in NextJs all work as expected, but when I called from the server side the endpoints fails.

Axios config:

```
function createHttpClient(baseURL) {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
}
```

When I called an endpoint from server side all works as expected, if we see the request we this shows both cookies, the XSRF-TOKEN and final_draw_session (httponly)

[image]
[image]

The problem is in the server side when I want to call an endpoint from the Page to use Static Site Generation:

On the page I get both cookien and I pass the valeus as parameters:

```
export default async function Page() {

  const fds = cookies().get('final_draw_session')?.value;
  const xsrf = cookies().get(XSRF_TOKEN)?.value;

  try {
    const response = await CategoryService.getAll(fds, xsrf);
    const categories = response.data.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }


  return (
    <CategoryView categories={{}} />
  )
}
```

and in the service I set the cookies

```
class CategoryService {

  async getAll(fds, xsrf) {

    httpAPIClient.defaults.headers.common['Cookie'] = `final_draw_session=${fds}; XSRF-TOKEN=${xsrf}`

    return await httpAPIClient.get('/categories', {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        'X-Xsrf-Token': xsrf
      }
    })
  }

}
```

After this I got a 401 UnAuthorize, if we see the request the cookies are sent:

[image]

but I see a difference in Laravel, When I print the cookies come from the client side these are:

```
[2023-09-11 07:59:30] local.INFO: array (
  'final_draw_session' => 'BYt1eG5U7hkvnxOSKXRRuaiGDWd2k39nUT1C8Wi5',
  'XSRF-TOKEN' => 'tnbIt9so383tU5IkCMKF7ZKEqyPnCl0hrxCTe9qi',
)
```

but the cookies that come from server side are:

```
[2023-09-11 07:58:19] local.INFO: array (
  'final_draw_session' => 'eyJpdiI6ImRjVnhvQlVxVkZvcXl6VTIvakZmU1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoicnlDUUwzMENMZVNCVlF0eTFZdXc5Zk9yODRzbXJ4TWJCUTFBNldENU4yNWhQWWhzMWZ3YkltKzM3bFA0R3ErTHNiQ3dQQnluZm9uaU0wM2JaaDcvQW9ETmpRK0kvS2NFZ0pzc1FjdEVDcXBxVzBUK1ZDWFBkOXNWbXRxbzdkSWwiLCJtYWMiOiI3ZGQ1Yjg0YTVmZDUzN2EwYTA0ZGUxYzMzMWE2MDY0Yjg2ZWMwMTg0NWZjNDMyYzQxMzczZTFjMzMzOTAwODJlIiwidGFnIjoiIn0=',
  'XSRF-TOKEN' => 'eyJpdiI6Ik1XL2dJejl4OXRjWlJKMzlUYm81ZGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiYVllMWl4bVIvVklWZDh2NDliMXEvcmRpeTYzcEV5RlZ4d3V0S1pGdHVLYnFNT09ObzdGdmcyYklXcVZpZkxaTnNhTjNFblVSN0RmTy96eHMvUUI1clFML2FBMjhkTHl1WStZNTczZ3M3Qlp0ZWJQTXNNNWhmODM1M2FSSDRyV2UiLCJtYWMiOiIwZDYzZTI1YmI4YjgxYTg5NzdlNjcwZDgzODE5OGMzOTRiNTY0MzAxMjExODRmNTNmYzQwNTMzMDJiMDhlZjE3IiwidGFnIjoiIn0=',
)
```

For some reason, Laravel encode the cookies that come from client side (I think) but I don't have idea what could be the reason.